# prove that e^x is not Lipschitz on R

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I know that the definition of Lipschitz function is:
If A⊆R and f:A→ R is function. Then, f is said to be Lipschitz on A if there exists a constant K>0 such that,|f(x)−f(y)|≤K|x−y| for all x,y∈A.
but how to prove that e^x is not Lipschitz on R?

Comment: It would imply that $$
e^{x + 1}  - e^x  < K \Leftrightarrow e^x (e - 1) < K \Rightarrow e^x  < K
$$ for all $x>0$, i.e., the exponential would be bounded.

Comment: can i use it directly to prove it is not uniform continuous on R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$e^x$ is not uniformly continuous and so is not Lipschitz. Take for example $x_n=\ln n,\ $ $y_n=\ln(n+1)$ then $y_n-x_n\to 0$ but $e^{y_n}-e^{x_n}\to 1$. Roughly speaking $e^x$ diverges to $+\infty$ with big velocity, bigger than a linear function

Comment: It would be nice if you change '$e^x$ converges to $\infty$' to '$e^x$ goes unbounded.'

Comment: A better change than '$e^x$ goes unbounded' would be '$e^x$ diverges to $\infty$', which is used in some calculus textbooks nowadays (such as Fitzpatrick's).

Comment: ok replacement is done

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
This kind of problem can be easily tackled using proof by contradiction.

Suppose $e^x$ is Lipschitz on $\R$. Then, there is a constant $L > 0$ such that for all $x,y \in \R$, $|e^x - e^y| \leq L|x-y|$. But according to the mean value theorem, there is $c\in (x,y)$ such that
$$
\frac{e^x - e^y}{x - y} = e^c
$$
Therefore, if we raise both $x$ and $y$, it can be arbitrarily large and of course, it can be larger than any $L > 0$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Because the derivative isn't bounded.
Convexity makes it very straighforward, though still true while being not convex.
$$f(y) - f(x) \geq f'(x) (y-x) $$